# Understanding Enhanced Entity-Relationship Generalization Hierarchy Principles

Tags: database-design, erd

I was given this exercise:

> (T/F and justify)
>
> It can be said that **an entity** related to another entity through a
>    generalization hierarchy:
>
> a) will always have a total participation with respect to the "parent"
>
> b) will always inherit the relationships of the "parent"

**My current considerations**

- Well, I think *a)* is true because it must be related to the other entity (that's the meaning of "total participation").
- I have no idea about *b)*.

I do not understand such a question. Can you clear my mind?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.jalowiec.org/phillip/cgc/cis164ag/datamodeling/dm/hierarchies.html):

> A generalization hierarchy is a structured grouping of entities that
>   share common attributes.

In the example in the article, they use a Person as the generalized entity, and derive Faculty, Staff and Student from the Person.

There are also rules that govern a generalized entity:

> - Each instance of the supertype entity must appear in at least one
>     subtype
> - an instance of the subtype must appear in the supertype
> - a subtype can not be related to more than one supertype
> - generalization hierarchies may be nested by having the subtype of one
>     hierarchy be the supertype for another

From this, I deduce that the answer must be True, based on the fourth "rule".

Comment: Thank you for replying!
Have you got any idea about b) ?

Comment: As I said, I think the answer is true for both statements. I’ve never personally heard of generalized entities.

Comment: Ohh, it is okay!
Can i ask you something?
Have you got any idea if THE entity cant have own defined relations?
Can this entity be weak with respect to another entity, that is different from the parent?

Comment: I mean, following the statement:
It can be said that an entity related to another entity through a generalization hierarchy:
-cannot have own defined relations
-Can this entity be weak with respect to another entity, that is different from the parent?

This is really complicated :(